# Using Spring Boot Thymeleaf by do not run as a web application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a Spring Boot application that uses Thymeleaf for email templating. My application is not a web application though.

However, when including the spring boot starter thymeleaf dependency:

`compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')`

Spring MVC is transitively included and eventually Servlet.class in my class path signaling that my application is a web application... which then has the undesirable result of running my application in the Tomcat servlet container (by default on port 8080).

How can I use the features of Spring Boot Thymeleaf (such as configuring in a props file ala https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) without my application running as a web application?

Comment: Posted a solution but there may be a better option such as including a Thymeleaf dependency that does not bring in other unneeded dependencies (such as Spring Web MVC) yet still allows configuring Thymeleaf via a props file. Will mark a better option as the answer.

Comment: As of Spring Boot 2.0, the Thymeleaf starter doesn't bring MVC transitively anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the following property as follows prevents the Spring Boot application from running as web application:

`spring.main.web-environment=false`